# structinit with list of two ints is reduced to one int

Tags: c++

I tried to initialise a struct with variables.   but in case i use type name = (values...) its only using the last element to initialise. it doesn't looks right for me but i don't know if its undefined behaviour, a compiler bug or something else. I would except a error message or initialise with more elements.

code:

```
struct funct {
    funct(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "init with one\t" << i << std::endl;
    }
    funct(int i, int j)
    {
        std::cout << "init with two\t" << i << "\t" << j << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    funct tempa = funct(42);
    funct tempb = 43;
    funct tempc = funct(44, 45);
    funct tempd = (46, 47); // thats the compiling thing
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
init with one   42
init with one   43
init with two   44      45
init with one   47
```

why is it this way and not init with 2 or a compileerrormessage?

compiler: g++ (GCC) 5.3.0

Comment: COMMA OPERATOR.

Comment: BTW, try using `{}` braces instead of `()` parentheses.  http://rextester.com/XDDDLA10902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ben said, it's the comma operator that's causing an issue.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator

> In a comma expression E1, E2, the expression E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded, and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2 begins

by doing `a = (b,c)` you are effectivly setting `a = c` and discarding b

Comment: Thanks! the quote explains it perfect for me, Thanks Ben, too

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help. If you are satisfied with the answer can you mark it as answered? Helps other users see a correct soloution